# How to synchronize databases in different Computers in a Lan

Tags: database, vb.net

I have my client app installed in many computers, each computer is connected via LAN. Each Client app uses its own SQL database. I need to synchronize the databases in each computer so that every client app has the same data. How can I achieve this using VB.net (VS 2010 , Winforms)

Comment: Do they have a local SQL database each? Do you have a server application running somewhere? Have they any means of communication with each other or some central location?

Comment: Yes they have a local database. There is also a server application which may or may not be available. There is no central location of data.

Comment: Perhaps you could be a bit more vague. Synch data? Synch schema?

Comment: I am working under VS2010,Winforms

Answer (score 0):

One way is with queue tables. Put an insert/update trigger on the tables to push any changes into a qeuue. If the table row was inserted, then updated twice, then the queue would have insert, update, update info in it. Then clients request changes from the queue based on the last time the pulled from the queue. The advantage of queues is the load stays small. You may have a table with 100,000 rows but you only download the 3 or 4 edits you need.

Another technique is to grab the entire table. Do a bulk insert to a staging table. Then do a set based update/insert to update existing rows, insert new rows.

Any solution you come up with will have the 800 pound gorilla in the room. That is merging. If a 2 user's submit conflicting data edits to the same row you have a problem. You can reduce the chance by syncing more often. A queue table lends it self better for syncing often as you only sync the new edits since last time. If your very very lucky the nature of your app will have each client only touching it's "own" data so merging would not be an issue.

You are in a LAN environment. Just have 1 database that all the clients access.  This is the traditional model for relational database applications and works very well.

Comment: I can't have a single database because there is no guarantee that the server will be always available.

Comment: I am not able to clearly understand what you meant by queuing , if possible can you put up  a sample code or provide a link to the same ?